# Add a description/hint field in the admin page of a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

I made a plugin and now I'm making an admin page for it. I know how to properly add a field in an admin page but do you know how I can add an description/hint field [like this (grey text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW6rS.jpg)?

Thanks

Comment: What does your code currently look like for just adding the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert something like this:

```
<p class="description">This is my description</p>
```

The `description` class is a built in WP class that will produce the style of text you pointed out in your image.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I was thinking about a harder solution than <p class="description">